# ChartJS getting an unwanted line between first data point and last data point

Tags: chart.js

I am getting an additional unwanted line between the first data set point and last data set point. (please view the image)[image: problem]

I have double checked my data source and they are all of same size and there are no NaN or Null values as wel. Any help is really appreciated.

background: ChartJS + AngularCLI

Following is the configuration

```
this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: dates,
        datasets: [
          {
            data: total,
            borderColor: '#743cba',
            fill: false,
            label : 'Total Cases'
          },
          {
            data: passed,
            borderColor: '#3cba9f',
            fill: false,
            label : 'Passed'
          },
          {
            data: fail,
            borderColor: '#ba3c3c',
            fill: false,
            label: 'Failed'
          },
          {
            data: lsf_fail,
            borderColor: '#00cbff',
            fill: false,
            label: 'LSF (Failure)'
          }/*,
          {
            data: improved,
            borderColor: '#3cb5ba',
            fill: false,
            label: 'Improved'
          },
          {
            data: unfinished,
            borderColor: '#e9fc16',
            fill: false,
            label: 'Unfinished'
          }*/
        ]
      },
      options: {
        elements: {
          line: {
            tension: 0,
          }
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{ display: true }],
          xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            autoSkip: true,
            time: {
              unit: 'week',
              stepSize: 1
            },
            display: true
          }]
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'SDOC LSF Metrics',
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, sort your data in order from earliest to latest and it will fix it.